# Add a class object into another class in C#

Tags: c#, class

I have two classes, the one is called Degree and the other is called Uprogram. And I want to add a single variable in UProgram to hold a Degree object. How can I do it?

```
class UProgram
    {
       //private member variables for UProgram
        private string programName;
        private string departmentName;
```

```
    //public properties for UProgram
    public string ProgramName
    {
        get { return programName; }
        set { programName = value; }
    }
    public string DepartmentName
    {
        get { return departmentName; }
        set { departmentName = value; }
    }  
}
```

class Degree
    {
        //private member variables for Degree
        private string degreeType;
        private string degreeName;

`//public properties for Degree
    public string DegreeType
    {
        get { return degreeType; }
        set { degreeType = value; }
    }
    public string DegreeName
    {
        get { return degreeName; }
        set { degreeName = value; }
    }
}`

Comment: Can't you just add a field like `private Degree myDegree;`?

Comment: What have you tried/researched? It is literally one of the first things demonstrated on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173110.aspx) for objects

Comment: As a side note, if you are not going to do anything in the `get` and `set` properties other than get and set the underlying `private` member, just use the automatic property syntax and skip the backing variable: `public string DepartmentName { get; set; }`

Comment: Homework question from C# course on edX...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the same way you added the string properties:

```
class UProgram
{
    //private member variables for UProgram
    private string programName;
    private string departmentName;
    private Degree degree;

    //public properties for UProgram
    public string ProgramName
    {
        get { return programName; }
        set { programName = value; }
    }
    public string DepartmentName
    {
        get { return departmentName; }
        set { departmentName = value; }
    }

    public Degree Degree
    {
        get { return degree; }
        set { degree = value; }
    }
}
```

Now you could provide an appropriate constructor to pass the degree object or simply use the property:

```
UProgram prog = new UProgram();
Degree degree = new Degree { DegreeName = "Foo", DegreeType = "type" };
prog.Degree = degree;
```

Comment: And how can I Instantiate a degree object that I have already rather than make a new Degree? I have the Degree degree1 = new Degree(); with all its properties and now that I am making a new Uprogram I want to connect the degree1 with the new UProgram.

Comment: @foldyourdesign: what is the problem? Just assign your `degree1` instead of the `degree` in my sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Make a property of type `Degree` in  `UProgram`

Answer (score 1):

```
class UProgram
{
   //private member variables for UProgram
    private string programName;
    private string departmentName; 
    private Degree __degree;

//public properties for UProgram
public string ProgramName
{
    get { return programName; }
    set { programName = value; }
}
public string DepartmentName
{
    get { return departmentName; }
    set { departmentName = value; }
}  
public Degree UProgDegree
{
    get{return __degree;}
    set {__degree = value;}
}
```

}